Swiper Elements won't show in angular
I am having major issues with Swiper Elements. I do all the placements but then i get the slide coming back as a  or List item.

The main.ts looks like this
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import {register as registerSwiperElements} from 'swiper/element/bundle';


registerSwiperElements();

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

the html looks like this
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
<swiper-container class="my-5" slides-per-view="3" grid-rows="3" mousewheel-force-to-axis="true">
    <swiper-slide class="slidee">Slide 1</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide class="slidee">Slide 2</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide class="slidee">Slide 3</swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
  
  </div>
  </div>

I had it on a different app and it worked just fine.
Now the issue persists.

Could you make CodePen or Sandbox with your issue? And keep in mind changing in relation to Angular what they made... here

in your app.components.ts
`import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle'
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
register();
}
`
Then in app.module.ts
inside @NgModule before imports add
schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
Then in HTML page try
<swiper-container  initial-slide="0"  slides-per-view="1" (swiperslidechange)="onSlideChange($event)" >     <swiper-slide *ngFor="let slide of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" >       <div class="swiper-slide-content">         <h2>Slide {{ slide }}</h2>       </div>     </swiper-slide>   </swiper-container>
